# How to setJobEndNotificationURI in the new mapreduce API ?

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, mapreduce

I know `org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf.setJobEndNotificationURI` can register a callback url to a hadoop job which can be called after the completion of the job, but in the new mapreduce api (I mean the `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce` package), the `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job` does not include a such kind of API.

What's the equivalent of `setJobEndNotificationURI` in the new mapreduce API?

Comment: The question was in the title. I'm adding it to the body for more clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `-Djob.end.notification.url` as an argument to your job . Else,

```
job.getConfiguration().set("job.end.notification.url","http url")
```

should do good.